# Rational numbers and coordinates

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vectors, combinations, rational-numbers

Due to my poor English, I make the following question from [this](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2019/10/TangiibleIInerim101219.pdf) paper:
What does it mean

**are identical off of their N Tails**

in the snippet below:
I.e. what does it technically mean ?

[image]

Comment: @DietrichBurde The last but one.

Comment: Ah, I see. It becomes pretty clear if we make an example. So let's take $k=2$ and $x=(1/2,5/3)$. Now let's do everything with $x$. For $y$ take some example so that $x,y$ are order equivalent. First, what is the $N$ tail shift of $x$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $x$ itself ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde But $x$ has **no** integer coordinates. They are fractional : $1/2$ and $5/3$ ...

Comment: Ah, good. I thought, the fractional part was meant. Yes, then it is $x$. This is the way I would proceed. Until finally one sees what it means that it is off the same distance, so "identically off". Everything first with examples.

Comment: @DietrichBurde To **no** coordinate ?

Comment: Well, yes, then take a better $x$, say $x=(0,1/2)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The N shift is then $(1,1/2)$

Comment: Do this until you have some examples $x,y$ fitting to the definition 2.2.2.6. Then from this data set we can solve the problems with the "English" because we understand what should be meant (like you showed me just 2 minutes ago with Definition 2.2.2.4. Now learn how to help yourself).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I now think that **identical off** means restricted to integer coordinates are order equivalent, is this correct ?